# Looping through column and updating Blank cells in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, loops, filter, count

I am trying to update all blank cells in column to allow my filtering to work. Here is my code as it stands:

```
 Sub MyLoop()

 Dim i As Integer
 Dim var As String
 Dim LastRow As Long

 LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

 For i = 1 To LastRow
    IF Cells(i, 4).Value<>"" Then 
      var = Cells(i, 4).Value
 End If

 Cells(i, 2).Value = var       'Assign value to column 2

 Next i

 End Sub
```

The image below shows the result of how my code works which I know is wrong. As you can see from Column H what I am trying to do is where the Level = 2 then take the value for Trailer ID and update Trailer ID2 with that value. As you can see as soon as I have a different Trailer Reg it then continues to use the new value.

[image: Current Result].

I would like to basically assign the value on Level 2 (Column G) and copy value to (Column H) under all groups below i.e. > Level 2 are complete. So when you hit a new Level 2 it starts again. This is the result if how I would like this to work:

[image: Final Result once Resolved]

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always try to fully qualify your code.

Your code doesn't seems to do what you described, this should do:

For every row

1. Check if Level (Column C) is 2 - Store the Trailer ID if true
2. Insert the current row's Trailer ID if it exist or else, insert the stored Trailer ID in Column H

   Sub MyLoop()

   ```
   Dim i As Long
   Dim LastRow As Long
   Dim trailerID As String

   With Sheet1 'Change to the correct worksheet reference

       LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

       For i = 2 To LastRow 'This should start from row 2 or 3? After the header row
           If .Cells(i, 3).Value = 2 Then 'Check the value in Column C (Level) if it's 2
               trailerID = .Cells(i, 7).Value
           End If

           If .Cells(i, 7).Value = vbNullString Then
               .Cells(i, 8).Value = trailerID      'If Trailer ID column is empty, take the last stored Trailer ID from Level 2
           Else
               .Cells(i, 8).Value = .Cells(i, 7).Value 'If not empty, take from the current row's Trailer ID
           End If
       Next i
   End With
   ```

   End Sub